# Java NumberFormatException Skip Line

Tags: java, io, numberformatexception

I'm writing a program that reads in  a list of numbers. Such as:

```
45
63
74g
34.7
75
```

I simply want my program to skip lines that contain any letters in them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

If it makes a difference, here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ScoreReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            String currentLine;

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("QuizScores.txt"));
            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                int sum = 0;

                String[] nums = currentLine.split("\\s+");
                for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
                    if (num != -1) {
                        sum += num;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(sum / nums.length);
            }
        } catch (IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (NumberFormatException err) {

        }

        finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (IOException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems your input file contain only one number in each line, but your code try to find the average between the numbers in same line. is that the file is just sample ?

Comment: The code is a sample/work in progress.

Comment: i understand the code is sample/work in progress. i did asked about the file format.

Comment: Hmm, it seems you're right. I can't get it to look at the list as a whole instead of a single line. Any tips?

Comment: see my answer , i cant describe in comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an exception is thrown, execution jumps to the catch block. In what you have, this is after the loop, so the loop doesn't continue, just add a `try` around `parseInt`.

```
try {
   String currentLine;

   reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("QuizScores.txt"));
   while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

       int sum = 0;
       String[] nums = currentLine.split("\\s+");
       for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
           try{
               int num = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
               if (num != -1) {
                   sum += num;
               }
           } catch( NumberFormatException nfe )
           {
              // maybe log it?
           }
       }

       System.out.println(sum / nums.length);
   }
} catch (IOException err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
} 
// catch (NumberFormatException err) {}
finally {
    try {
       if (reader != null){
           reader.close();
    } catch (IOException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also note, you are using `Integer.parseInt` which will throw an exception with the input `"34.7"`, so maybe you wish to use `Double.parseDouble`

Comment: While your answer is likely what the poster wanted, using Double.parseDouble does allow letters without breaking, so technically is not correct (think normal representation). Begs the question - what exactly did he mean by contains letters? Is it really line contains letters (in which case Regexp is the way to go), or line is a genuine number?

Comment: What exactly does your comment "maybe log it" mean?

Comment: @Ben it is customary to not leave any exception unattended. Do you expect quiz scores to have letters in them? In that case - don't you want to process those lines in some other fashion? If not - wouldn't you like to know if you missed some lines after reading a 10000 line file, or what was in those lines to fix it or send an error report?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regex? Like for example:

```
 if (currentLine.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*")) {
     //letters contained.
 } else {
     //no letters contained.
 }
```

see regex demo: http://regex101.com/r/rQ6oR1

Comment: Why not just catch the exception `parse<NumericType>` throws?

Comment: Yep catching the parse Exception is a good way to do it. I just took the question `I simply want my program to skip lines that contain any letters in them` literally ;-) @clcto

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
 import java.io.*;

    public class ScoreReader {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                String currentLine;

                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("QuizScores.txt"));
                while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    int sum = 0;

                    String[] nums = currentLine.split("\\s+");
                    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

                        if (isInt(num)) {
                            sum += num;
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println(sum / nums.length);
                }
            } catch (IOException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            } 


            finally {
                try {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                } catch (IOException err) {
                    err.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

public boolean isInt(String num)

    {
        boolean flag=false;


        try
        {
            int i=Integer.parseInt(num);
            flag=true;
        }

        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return flag;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment. if your file contain one number per line . then this would be easiest way.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("QuizScores.txt"));
        int sum = 0;
        int count =0;
        while( sc.hasNext()){
            String tmpNum = sc.next();
            if (isNumeric(tmpNum)){
                sum = sum + (int) Double.parseDouble(tmpNum); // if you want t capture in double use Double instead.
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum/count);


public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
    {
        return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.
    }
```